# Telling Typedoc Not to Load Jasmine Annotations

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, jasmine, typedoc

I'm getting this error in an Angular library project:

```
Using TypeScript 3.7.5 from /home/ole/Github/validatorjs-workspace/projects/validatorjs/node_modules/typescript/lib
Error: /home/ole/Github/validatorjs-workspace/node_modules/@types/jasmine/ts3.1/index.d.ts(20)
 Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: beforeAll, beforeEach, afterAll, afterEach, describe, fdescribe, xdescribe, it, fit, xit, expect, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL, CustomMatcherFactory, CustomEqualityTester
Error: /home/ole/Github/validatorjs-workspace/node_modules/@types/jasmine/ts3.1/index.d.ts(308)
 All declarations of 'ArrayContaining' must have identical type parameters.
Error: /home/ole/Github/validatorjs-workspace/node_modules/@types/jasmine/ts3.1/index.d.ts(312)
 All declarations of 'ObjectContaining' must have identical type parameters.
Error: /home/ole/Github/validatorjs-workspace/node_modules/@types/jasmine/ts3.1/index.d.ts(359)
 All declarations of 'message' must have identical modifiers.
```

Can we configure typedoc not to look at the Jasmine annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going up to the workspace project and removing `@types/jasmine` from `package.json` and running `npm i` fixes the problem.